# youtube API CSS Styling

Tags: javascript, css, youtube

Youtube has recently changed its youtube API, and deprecated the javascript and flash players .. so a lot of solution in stackoverflow or any other websites are old now and not helping :( ,,

I am trying to change the colors of the youtube players elements via CSS, for example I used this code:

```
path.ytp-large-play-button-bg {
fill: yellowgreen;}
```

for changing the youtube play button color .. but it doesn't work..
I searched a lot but I didn't see anything about styling the new youtube Iframe
I tried [Youtbe player demo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo) too, but it doesn't give any powerful style changing option, (I can change nothing, even the colors there are just white and red)..
Is there any other ways to style the youtube API ?

Comment: You can't apply any custom CSS to cross-domain iFrames. The only styling you'll able to do is stuff that is explictly allowed through the API - which as far as I'm aware is limited / non-existant.

Consider another video host if the content belongs to you.

Comment: Thank you for this information .. , I think youtube should give us more options in embedding their youtube player.. giving us more colors or another features ..

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, it would be nice but they have a brand to protect so I understand why they don't.